# Running my own system into a virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine

Just a curiosity, (I'm not an expert), can I run my current operating system in a Virtual Machine? (I'm on a Mac 10.5.8)

I mean, every VM software I've seen online claim to "Run Windows on your Mac", "Run Unix..." etc.
Can I run my own OS into a VM while I am using that OS? Like 2 different isolated sessions one inside the other.

Sorry for my non-technical jargon.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that this is what you mean, but I'm running MacOS and Windows programs side by side at the same time using Parallels Desktop just fine. Nice and still somewhat disturbing to run Visual Studio side by side with XCode on the same screen :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac does not allow you to run their OS in a VM. You can try installing the OS on a Virtual machine, but I have yet to have a successful install on VirtualBox.